# How to make s WPF menu look like a Windows Forms ToolStripMenu?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I am new to WPF. And by new I mean I just started it today after getting .net 3.5. I usually do GUI Development in Windows Forms and like the awesome ToolStripMenu. But when I saw the WPF Menu, it was so ugly that it reminded me of my Win32 Api days. Is there any way to change the style of a WPF menu to make it look like a Windows Forms menu?

Comment: You mean this one (WinForms picture) http://www.code-magazine.com/ArticleImage.aspx?QuickID=0601071&Image=fig_007.gif ?

Comment: Yup. notice the fancy gradient winforms has on its menus and toolbars

Comment: i have been waiting for 20 minutes and have got only like 12 views and **ONE RESPONSE?** is everyone dead?

Comment: He he - yes I think everyone is dead .. by the way yes you can get the toolstrip to look like the forms one - and even cooler. Did you try the wpf toolstrip?

Comment: @burning: maybe [winforms] just doesn't draw a crowd...

Comment: @Rune Does the wpf toolstrip support drop down menus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

An introduction to styling and templating:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx

A new styling for toolbar
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772.aspx

Alternatively search for 
wpf ToolBar style

Edit: 
Yes - but add a menu like this and the toolbar alters the menu style (paste in new project):

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ToolBarTray >
  <ToolBar >
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Hey">
      <MenuItem Header="lo"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Ho">
      <MenuItem Header="la"></MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: I wanted to know about menus not toolbars. But still this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome , thanks! I was wrong about WPF , its even better than windows forms! an upvote and tick!

Answer (score 1):

The Menu, like most WPF controls has very little styling by default.

But that's just by default, you can add your own styles and outshine WinForms very easily .

Just a little starter:

```
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
        <Menu.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Menu.Background>
        <MenuItem Header="_File" >
```

Comment: Thanks! So you can even decide what gradient to use!

Comment: Yes, with as many points and colors as you like. Also look at ImageBrush, RadialGradientBrush, ... And do use Styles.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Does it have bad effects on memory usage & Performance?